# Get the length of a single line from a file with Low-Level I/O functions

Tags: c, function, file, low-level

I am writing a routine to check if a username has already been registered on an internal database.
In particular the following function "should" return the length of only one single line of the database:

```
int line_bytes(int database, off_t line){
    int c, len;
    lseek(database, line, SEEK_CUR);
    for(len = 0; read(database, &c, 1) == 1; len++)
        if(c == '\n');
            return len;
}
```

Though, it returns the whole file length (all the chars on the file). So the question: is the problem read()? The low-input function read all the file in one single cycle and return the whole file length?

To help, the database format is:

```
username \t password\n
...\n
...\n
last-username \t last-passwotd\n
```

Comment: You are reading 1 byte into `int`, and then checking the whole (4-byte?) `int`. Did you mean `char c`?

Comment: It's unclear whther the edit to remove the offending `;` was to correct a typo, or to fix the error. It's thrown the code posted into doubt. Always copy/paste the *exact* code.

Comment: Thanks. This was the problem. Just to be clear: the way I was doing is wrong because, reading 1 byte of `char` into a 4 byte `int`, left memory not initialized (hence garbage) on so the char `'\n'` was never found?

Comment: Sorry about the edit

Comment: Just FYI, reading one `char` at a time is extremely slow.  System calls are *very* expensive (especially on modern x86-64 Linux with Spectre and Meltdown mitigation), tens of thousands of times slower then the amortized per-char cost of `memchr(buf, '\n', read_len)` to search in chunks of up to 8kiB for example, depending on how much data is in the rest of the file.  (32kiB would be even more efficient for bulk I/O, but most lines are much shorter than that so if you only want a single line at a given seek position, 4k or 8k is very likely to get it. But not guaranteed, so it needs more code.)

Comment: Hints to make your life easier: Build with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`. Always use `{}` even when not required. Always check and *print/log* errors of any IO (except stdout/stderr output) functions (here `lseek` and `read`).

Comment: @FrancescoMobilia `read()` does not exist in the standard C library.  Add a tag for the compiler/library you are using.

Comment: Francesco Mobilia, If input was only `"\n"`, would you want a return value of 0 or 1?  If input was only `""` (no more input), would you want a return value of 0 or what?

Answer (score 0):

You have a `;` on the if-statement. Remove it. ;)
Also add a return after the loop, like `return -1;`

Your code does erroneously:

```
int line_bytes(int database, off_t line) {
    char c; int len;
    lseek(database, line, SEEK_CUR);
    for (len = 0; read(database, &c, 1) == 1; len++)
        if (c == '\n') {
            ;
        }
    }
    return len;
}
```

Better `char c` as when 1 byte is read the other bytes of the int are uninitialized, and on a big-endian the char is misplaced.